# how to bind data in footer of gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview and I have to bind data in gridview as well as the footer of the gridview. I have tried many things but nothing is working. Can anyone tell me what I have to do can? I bind the gridview in the footer with the same query or I have to write diffrent query for gridview and footer. Below is my work. What I have tried I write diffrent query for both gridview and footer

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView grdview = ystem.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView)sender);
Label lblenqid = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblenqid1");
Label lblactualcost = (Label)grdview.FooterRow.FindControl("Label44") as Label;
Label lblpackagecost = (Label)grdview.FooterRow.FindControl("Label42") as Label;
Label lbldriver = (Label)grdview.FooterRow.FindControl("Label46") as Label;
objHotel.Tour_DetailVehiclePackageCost(lblenqid.Text,
                blactualcost,lblpackagecost,lbldriver);
```

plz help me thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void yourNiceGridViewControl_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
  {
    TextBox myTextBox = e.Row.FindControl("txtFooter") as TextBox;

    if( myTextBox != null ) 
    {

      myTextBox.Tex= ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["MyFirend"].ToString();
    }
  }
}
```

Try this.

Comment: can you please tell me for this where i hv to write query becz im wrking in n tier architecture please let me know

Comment: if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
  {
     GridView grdview1 = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("GridView1");
     Label lblenqid = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblenqid1");
Label lbactualcost=(Label)grdview1.FooterRow.FindControl("Label44");
Label lblpcgcost = (Label)grdview1.FooterRow.FindControl("Label42");
Label lbldriver = (Label)grdview1.FooterRow.FindControl("Label46");
 string enqid = lblenqid.Text;
 objHotel.Tour_DetailVehiclePackageCost(enqid, lblactualcost, lblpackagecost, lbldriver);
            }i wriiten this code can anyone tell where iam wrong